# Are there any niceties for dealing with custom [LaTeX] environments in LyX?

Tags: latex, lyx

I have some LaTeX environments and commands I'd like to bind to keyboard shortcuts, and (optimally) have them handled a little better than:

```
<LaTeX env -- "\mycommand{">   regular lyx code   <LaTeX env -- "}">
```

Any tricks would be useful.

Comment: I wonder if you'd have more luck at tex.se.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=shortcuts